# How to define multiple query parameters in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, query-string

I need to get required customer information on multiple parameters like first name, last name, mobile etc.

I have decided to use queryparams for this purpose.

If I define my methods as below

```
@GetMapping("/customers")
    public ResponseEntity<EntityModel<Customer>> findCustomerByFirstName(@RequestParam(required = false) String firstName) {
        System.out.println();
        return service.findCustomerByFirstName(firstName) //
                .map(assembler::toModel) //
                .map(ResponseEntity::ok) //
                .orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
    }
//Last-name
@GetMapping("/customers")
    public ResponseEntity<EntityModel<Customer>> findCustomerByLastName(@RequestParam(required = false, name = "lastName") String lastName) {
        return service.findCustomerByLastName(lastName) //
                .map(assembler::toModel) //
                .map(ResponseEntity::ok) //
                .orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
    }
```

Spring is giving me following exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'customerController' method
com.test.cas.controller.CustomerController#findCustomerByFirstName(String)
to {GET [/api/customers/]}: There is already 'customerController' bean method
com.test.cas.controller.CustomerController#findCustomerByLastName(String) mapped.
```

Any suggestion to overcome this issue is much appreciated.

Comment: You have two endpoint with same path and same HTTP method so Spring is not able to distinguish between them.

Comment: Both your endpoints can be called without parameter(`required = "false"` on each parameter), so there is no way to choose from them.

Comment: Yes both of my endpoints are same, looking for some suggestion to get my job done following the best practices.
I can change the endpoints and then I will end up like "/customers/firstname/{firstName}" and "/customers/lastname/{lastName}"
I am not sure if this comes under the best practices.
Need some advice here.

Answer (score 0):

Use only one Mapping to one method and do something like this.

```java
@GetMapping("/customers")
    public ResponseEntity<EntityModel<Customer>> findCustomerByFirstNameOrLastname(
@RequestParam(required = false) String firstName, 
@RequestParam(required = false) String lastName) {
        if (StringUtils.hasText(firstName))
            return service.findCustomerByFirstName(firstName) //
                .map(assembler::toModel) //
                .map(ResponseEntity::ok) //
                .orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
        if (StringUtils.hasText(lastName))
            return service.findCustomerByLastName(lastName) //
                .map(assembler::toModel) //
                .map(ResponseEntity::ok) //
                .orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
    }
```

This can be written with JPA Criteria specifications and a separate service layer, but just for the main idea.

Comment: I tried and this solutions works but again I am not sure if there is some better way of doing it, as my first-name, last-name and mobile-number will return ResponseEntity<EntityModel<Customer>> but other params like city and state will return ResponseEntity<CollectionModel<Customer>> which can't be accomodated in a single method.